# Failed to connect [10048]

Tags: bluetooth, winsock, bluecove

I've got this code on a button, when I press it I get the Error:

```
  Error: Exception connecting to NXT.
  Caused by lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommException: Open of NXT failed.
at lejos.pc.comm.NXTCommBluecove.open(NXTCommBluecove.java:136)
   Caused by javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException: Failed to connect; [10048]
 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.connect(Native Method)
Failed to connect to any NXT
```

I am posting because it was working fine yesterday but seems not to be working today.

```
btnConnectBot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (Cnt1){
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    Cnt1=!Cnt1;
                    txtConnState.setText("Off");
                    txtConnState.setForeground(Color.RED);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{   
                conn.addLogListener(new NXTCommLogListener() {
                public void logEvent(String message) {
                System.out.println(message);
                }

                public void logEvent(Throwable throwable) {
                System.err.println(throwable.getMessage());
                }
                });
                conn.setDebug(true);
                if (!conn.connectTo(txtBotName.getText(), NXTComm.LCP)) {
                System.err.println("Fallo de conexión");
                txtConnState.setText("Off");
                txtConnState.setForeground(Color.RED);
                System.exit(1);
                }
                Cnt1=!Cnt1;     
                txtConnState.setText("On");
                txtConnState.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

                if (chckbxLock_2.isSelected()){
                    btnConnectBot_2.doClick();
                }
                if (chckbxLock_1.isSelected()){
                    btnConnectBot_1.doClick();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

According to my research this is because the bluetooth port being used is being accessed by more than one instance. But I don't see how this happens in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Bluetooth virtual COM port configured for the remote device? Maybe it is opened by some program...

Or, does the error occur the first time you run your program? Are there any old copies of your program running -- check in taskmgr.exe